# Extending Bounds For Polygons -- Google Maps V3 Javascript API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My goal is to detect if a marker is within an oddly shaped polygon object (think 25 different points).    I have noticed that the LatLngBounds property, only contains two sets of LatLngs, even after using the .extend function, for example:

((34.347971491244955, -122.40966796875), (34.829586636768205, -120.9649658203125))

Is this normal behavior?

The code below is a tiny snippet of the program I am building, but contains the relevant information for how I am using the extend function.    Does anyone have any idea how to detect if a marker is within an oddly shaped polygon, if I can't use a combination of .extend() and .contains()?

```
var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray()); //get            
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


function extendBounds(bounds, coordinates) {
    for (b in coordinates) {
        bounds.extend(coordinates[b]);            
    };
    console.log(bounds.toString());
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bounds of a polygon is a rectangle.  If you want to detect if a marker is in the polygon use the containsLocation function in [google.maps.geometry.poly namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly), passing it the polygon and the position of the marker

> containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon) | boolean | Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.

Comment: `alert(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(house, polygon))`

Any reason why the above would be returning:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'`

I am importing the namespace like this:

`    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>`

Comment: Did you include the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries)?