# How to get google maps polygon bounds?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say if I search a district of a city on the google map, I got the results on the map as a polygon. My question is how can I get the bounds of that polygon?

I observed that regions, districts are delimited with dashed lines is there a possibility to get the bounds of a searched district or region?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending Bounds For Polygons -- Google Maps V3 Javascript API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114387/extending-bounds-for-polygons-google-maps-v3-javascript-api)

Comment: It is not the same question, I want to get the bounds of a searched district or region but I don' know how

Comment: So you don't have the polygon?  If the results of the search come from the geocoder, the results contain a bounds and an optional suggested viewport (which is a bounds object as well).  Please clarify your question with the Google Maps API v3 code you are using.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't ask the question well at all... My question is if I search let's say Duisburg Mitte (it is a district of Duisburg city Germany) I saw there a dashed lines which delimits the district from other districts. If I am zoom out a little bit the area inside those dashed lines background are changed to red, it looks like a polygon. The question is if it is possible to get the bounds of that area somehow?

Comment: Not (currently) from the Google Maps API v3.  You can create an enhancement request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), or maybe vote/star [this one](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109).  You can search for KML polygons.  Possibly the [Natural Earth Dataset in FusionTables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons/10875909#10875909) might contain the polygons you are looking for.