# How to check lat/lon in in drawn Poligon area or not

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a project where I have draw a Poligon using

```
PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.addAll(lat_longList);
    rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(5);
    rectOptions.fillColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    poliPolygon  = map.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

But now I want to check another lat/lon (line 22.00,88.011) falls in that polygon area or not. if that lat/lon is in that are then load a marker.

Please help on this issue.

Comment: PLease see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16114561/1424115

Comment: Actually, can you clarify.  Are you looking for a specific marker within a polygon or if a lat/lon falls within a polygon?

Comment: @RaySülzer the answers refer to google map v3 javascript not for android

Comment: this a javascript api example I am working with native java api.

Comment: @Ray I am looking for if a lat/lon falls within a polygon?

Comment: This might be useful: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

Comment: Lol, actually they use frames on that site.  This is the link: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geometry/Bounds.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the getPoints() of PolygonOptions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/model/PolygonOptions